# Why does Emacs replace quotation marks incorrectly in LaTeX mode?

Tags: emacs, latex, auctex

When writing LaTeX documents in Emacs, it usually automatically replaces quotation marks `"` by ``` `` ``` or `''`, as it should. But sometimes, it incorrectly replaces by `` "` ``  and `"'` instead. I am observing this in Emacs 23.4 supplied as version 23.4+1-4ubuntu1 in Ubuntu 13.04.

It happens in the below example:

```
\documentclass[danish]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
This is a "`test"'.
\end{document}
```

My guess is that babel and the language option `danish` is causing this together with AUCTeX. If I change it to `english` and reset AUCTeX, the problem disappears. If I change it back to `danish` and reset AUCTeX it re-appears.
How can I fix this?

Comment: That's gonna be a hard one if you can't pin down the elusive "sometimes".

Comment: Which languages are you loading with `babel` package?

Comment: @giordano I will get back to you on this as soon as I encounter a document again that causes this.

Comment: @ThomasArildsen another question: do you use AUCTeX or default Emacs TeX mode?

Comment: @giordano I am using AUCTeX.

Comment: @giordano The problem seems to appear when using the `danish` language option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AUCTeX has a special support for many languages, for example it can help inserting quotes.  For more information see the [AUCTeX manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Style-Files-for-Different-Languages).

If you don't like the default style of quotes inserted by AUCTeX for a specific language, you can override it customizing the `TeX-quote-language-alist` variable.  To do that add this to your `.emacs`:

```lisp
(setq TeX-quote-language-alist '(("danish" "``" "''" t)))
```

In this way pressing `"` button twice you will get ``` `` ``` or `''` according to context.  Instead, if you want to insert ``` `` ``` and `''` pressing `"` button just once, add the following code to your `.emacs`:

```lisp
(add-hook 'TeX-language-dk-hook
      (lambda ()
        (setq TeX-quote-language `("danish" "``" "''" ,TeX-quote-after-quote))))
```

Comment: I am in doubt what the official correct Danish quote marks are, but they are certainly not "`  and "'. I will have to figure that out.

Comment: I'm not a danish speaker, I can't help you in this regard. Change the variable according to your need, I just showed you how to do that `;-)`

Comment: Which looks exactly like what I need. Testing the above, I see that your command causes the quote marks to become ". Is that intended? I was guessing that it would cause them to become `` and '', but I am quite lisp-illiterate...

BTW, I am a native Dane, so I guess I should know the correct marks :o)

Comment: Press `"` twice.

Comment: @ThomasArildsen I expanded the answer, there is a solution to get opening and closing quotes pressing `"` once.